# AspectJ applying Around advice on methods that return void

Tags: aspectj

given a block of Advice like below:

```
@Around("execution(* com.myproject..*(..))")
public Object log(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable{

....
Object result = pjp.proceed();
......
return result;
}
```

I just want to know if I have a method that returns void, will this Advice get applied, and will that result in some kind of error?

Example:

```
package com.myproject.mypackage;

public Class MyClass {
    public void run() {
        // Will this method run properly as a result of 'pjp.proceed()' above?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried experimenting by running a few stub methods myself, I found that the Advice *will* get applied, and there will be no error other than those generated by the joinpoint itself.

Comment: I suggest you accept your own answer or just delete the question because you are just asking something you could easily have tried in two minutes, asking others to try it for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but trying something and confirming it with people that know it are two different things. I could have been lucky because I used a version of jdk that works this time, I could have tried it wrong by not understanding the aspectj language in the first place. To me an 'acceptable answer' is something that shows link to an official documentation; An answer that sounds like 'it works for me too' is up-votable at best ;)